# How to add a public class to a Cordova project using a plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to add this plugin ([SupportKit](https://github.com/supportkit/supportkit-cordova)) to a Crodova project I'm working on but I have really no idea about Android development (I'm more of an iOS dev), the problem I have and I would like to resolve is to know if there is a way to make this step from the docs:

```
Android

Init SupportKit(natively) in the Application class, for example:

public class MainApplication extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SupportKit.init(this, "your-supportkit-app-token");
    }
}
The javascript init call will not work in Android. It must be done natively.
```

easily using Cordova, maybe on the plugin.xml or any other way, any resource for where to start or any help wold be great!

Answer (score 0):

@Jeronimo Cosio,
Cordova/Phonegap does NOT use classes. It uses HTML5, Javascript and CSS. I think you want to use the code as a plugin. The only libraries we have in Cordova/Phonegap are plugins – and what is available with the webview library.

It appears the code you linked to is a plugin. If it is unclear how to do this from the general documentation, then ask the author of the plugin.

You may also want to read:
[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)